# How to create Calendar for Scheduling using ASP.NET C# for appointments and meetings

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I want to create a calendar for scheduling patient appointments, appointment history, reminders etc like Google calendar  using ASP.NET 3.5 and C# with SQL Server.

Comment: that's not a question, it's a statement

Answer (score 0):

I will suggeset [DevExpress libraries](http://www.devexpress.com/) or [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com). I used the DevExpress componenet for a Calendar webapp and they were quite simple to use.

Comment: any suggestion for a free one ?

Comment: No sorry. A lot of time've passed since I looked for alternatives

Answer (score 0):

There are some useful controls in [ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Default.aspx), amongst which [Calendar](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx).